# Getting a redirect that doesn't make sense

Tags: node.js, express, routes, stripe-payments

I am trying to save a stripe plan to my user but when I do that I get redirected to `/company/undefined` but that doesn't make sense to me since I have that nowhere in my code. I did a search through all files in the server directory and nothing came up.

I am not too sure what could be happening, in my route you will see an isAuth middleware, all it does it check if the user is logged in or not. Only redirects to `/` or passes next.

When I pass in a value a `req.body.plan` that is a valid non spaces stripe plan it works but when I introduce a space into it or anything that isn't a valid plan then it give the error 404 page.

I have included my code and an example morgan output for a request.

**Morgan output:**

```
GET /company/billing 304 9.932 ms - -
POST /company/plan 302 443.888 ms - 62
GET /company/undefined 404 9.528 ms - 1490
```

**Route:**

```
app.post('/company/plan',
isAuthenticated,
company.postPlan);
```

**postPlan controller:**

```
exports.postPlan = function(req, res, next){
  var plan = req.body.plan;
  var coupon = req.body.coupon;
  if (coupon) {
    req.user.isUsedCoupon = true;
  }
  var stripeToken = null;
  if(plan){
    plan = plan.toLowerCase();
  }

  if(req.user.stripe.plan == plan){
    req.flash('info',  'The selected plan is the same as the current plan.');
    return res.redirect('/user/settings');
  }

  if(req.body.stripeToken){
    stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
  }
  if(plan != 'silver'){
    if(!req.user.stripe.last4 && !req.body.stripeToken){
      req.flash('errors',  'Please add a card to your account before choosing a plan.');
      return res.redirect('/user/settings');
    }
  }



  User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    user.setPlan(plan, coupon, stripeToken, function (err) {
      var msg;

      if (err) {
        if(err.code && err.code == 'card_declined'){
          msg = 'Your card was declined. Please provide a valid card.';
        } else if(err && err.message) {
          msg = err.message;
        } else {
          msg = 'An unexpected error occurred.';
        }

        req.flash('errors', msg);
        return res.redirect();
      }
      req.flash('success',  'Plan has been updated.');
      res.redirect('/user/settings');
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Is this redirecting you with undefined? `return res.redirect();`  That occurs if there is an error during the callback of `user.setPlan`.

Comment: @dvsoukup Yes it redirects to `/company/undefined` it gives no error or stack trace either. I just changed that part you pointed out and now I get redirected back to the correct redirect but nothing happens, no error message flashed, nor a change to the user profile.

Comment: You won't see a stack trace because you're not throwing an error, but rather simply passing it to `req.flash`.  That is some other internal design you have going on.  But, I find it to be a potential issue in that you're setting the error message on the `req`, which is the request.  Shouldn't you set it on `res`, as that is your response back?

Comment: @dvsoukup Setting it on req.flash is the correct way of doing it even if it seems backwards. Take a look at the `connect-flash` package on npm/github and the examples it has. Should give you an idea why I did it this way.

As for the no stack trace, it normally should be outputting an error to the screen. Often not a stack trace but a simple error message.